# unable to set group permissions for a folder

Tags: linux, permissions

I need to give writing permissions within a folder for all the user in the www-data group.

So far, I tried to ad `myUser` to the group:

```
sudo usermod -a -G www-data myUser
```

Then, I changed the owner and the group of the folder:

```
sudo chgrp -R www-data shared_folder/
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data shared_folder/
```

and finally I tried to set the permissions:

```
sudo chmod g+w -R shared_folder/
```

This is the result of `ls -l` for the given folder (and for all its inner files):

```
drwxrwxr-x  4 www-data    www-data     4096 Feb 17 16:31 shared_folder
```

Now, I am not able neither to create a new file nor to modify an existing ones in the `shared_folder`.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

New user groups are only effective for new logins. A new login can be done by either logging out and then logging in again or by using another mechanism like `su` oder `sudo`.

Comment: That was the reason why..